# Export map series to PDF, with page name, using ArcPy ArcGIS Pro 2.7.1

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, export, pdf, map-series

I would like to export multiple PDF files from a map series, with page name as a output file.

I used this code:

```py
import arcpy, os, sys
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("LayoutName")[0] 
ms = lyt.mapSeries
print (ms)
for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1): 
    ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
    pageName = ms.pageRow.NAME
    print(pageName)
    lyt.exportToPDF(r"path", f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf")
print("Export Succeeded")
```

But, I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [1]:
Line 8:     lyt.exportToPDF(r"path to the folder", f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf")

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\utils.py, in fn_:
Line 191:   return fn(*args, **kw)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\_mp.py, in exportToPDF:
Line 1161:  return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.exportToPDF(*gp_fixargs((out_pdf, resolution, image_quality, compress_vector_graphics, image_compression, embed_fonts, layers_attributes, georef_info, jpeg_compression_quality, clip_to_elements, output_as_image, embed_color_profile), True)))

TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

Update section: This code works.

```py
import arcpy, os, sys
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")  
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("LayoutName")[0] 
ms = lyt.mapSeries
print (ms)
for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1): 
    ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
    pageName = ms.pageRow.NAME
    print(pageName)
    lyt.exportToPDF(os.path.join((r"X:\ST_Geo_Tec_en_cours_Maria",f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf"))
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual path, rather than hiding it as the error may be there?

Comment: Hi, here: lyt.exportToPDF(r"X:\ST_Geo_Tec\_en_cours_Maria", f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf") many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the code:

```
lyt.exportToPDF(r"path", f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf")
```

You are exporting the layout to pdf. You need to [read the help file](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm#M1_GUID-6DFB661B-D50A-4E3A-AE75-6884442AD100) and understand the functions syntax. According to the help file the second parameter is *resolution*, a number hence you getting the error message

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

You are providing a string which appears to be the name of the desired output file. Suggest you concatenate the path with name as:

```py
fn = r"X:\ST_Geo_Tec_en_cours_Maria\" + f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf"
lyt.exportToPDF(fn)
```

Comment: Hi, great, I got your point, and even if with your suggestion, it doesn't work, I find a partial solution, but only gets me 1 output and not all the pages of the map series, I can't figure out why, do you have any ideia?                                                              for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1): 
    ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
    pageName = ms.pageRow.NAME
    print(pageName)
lyt.exportToPDF(os.path.join(r"X:\ST_Geo_Tec_en_cours_Maria\,f"{ms.pageRow.NAME}_1.pdf"))
print("Export Succeeded")

Comment: Your comment is unreadable, edit your original question, typically you would tag on to the end of the question an "update" section.

Comment: @Hornbydd I should have read the help, instead of assuming the 2nd value was a file name parameter. Doh-me!

Comment: @KHibma, well the jokes on me, I up voted your answer, then realised today based upon Maria's response to you that there was something else amiss and then I read the help file and realised what the problem was! Something about being free on sin before casting the first stone comes to mind... :)